# Retrieving error Layer conv2d_3 expects 1 input(s), but it received 3 input tensors

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I have the following code trying to create resnet32 architecture and training the model. The code contains the model architecture of Resnet32 for the input shape it's throwing an error, saying ValueError: Layer conv2d_3 expects 1 input(s), but it received 3 input tensors.

```
from keras.datasets import cifar10
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()
X_train = X_train.astype('float32') 
X_test = X_test.astype('float32') 
X_train = X_train / 255.0 
X_test = X_test / 255.0
y_train = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train) 
y_test = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test) 
num_classes = y_test.shape[1]
```

Resnet Architecture

```
def building_block(X, filter_size, filters, stride=1):   
    X_shortcut = X
    # Reshape shortcut for later adding if dimensions change
    if stride > 1:
        X_shortcut = Conv2D(filters, (1, 1), strides=stride, padding='same')(X_shortcut)
        X_shortcut = BatchNormalization(axis=3)(X_shortcut) 
    X = Conv2D(filters, kernel_size = filter_size, strides=stride, padding='same')(X)
    X = BatchNormalization(axis=3)(X)
    X = Activation('relu')(X)
    X = Conv2D(filters, kernel_size = filter_size, strides=(1, 1), padding='same')(X)
    X = BatchNormalization(axis=3)(X)
    X = add([X, X_shortcut])  # Add shortcut value to main path
    X = Activation('relu')(X)
    return X
def create_model(input_shape, classes, name):
    # Define the input
    X_input = input_shape
    # Stage 1
    X = Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=3, strides=(1, 1), padding='same')(X_input)
    X = BatchNormalization(axis=3)(X)
    X = Activation('relu')(X)

    # Stage 2
    X = building_block(X, filter_size=3, filters=16, stride=1)
    X = building_block(X, filter_size=3, filters=16, stride=1)
    X = building_block(X, filter_size=3, filters=16, stride=1)
    X = building_block(X, filter_size=3, filters=16, stride=1)
    X = building_block(X, filter_size=3, filters=16, stride=1)

    # Stage 3
    X = building_block(X, filter_size=3, filters=32, stride=2)  # dimensions change (stride=2)
    X = building_block(X, filter_size=3, filters=32, stride=1)
    X = building_block(X, filter_size=3, filters=32, stride=1)
    X = building_block(X, filter_size=3, filters=32, stride=1)
    X = building_block(X, filter_size=3, filters=32, stride=1)

    # Stage 4
    X = building_block(X, filter_size=3, filters=64, stride=2)  # dimensions change (stride=2)
    X = building_block(X, filter_size=3, filters=64, stride=1)
    X = building_block(X, filter_size=3, filters=64, stride=1)
    X = building_block(X, filter_size=3, filters=64, stride=1)
    X = building_block(X, filter_size=3, filters=64, stride=1)

    # Average pooling and output layer
    X = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(X)
    X = Dense(classes, activation='softmax')(X)

    # Create model
    model = Model(inputs=X_input, outputs=X, name=name)
    return model

# Define optimizer and compile model
input_shape=X_train.shape[1:]
optimizer = optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0)
ResNet32 = create_model(input_shape=input_shape, classes=2, name='ResNet32')
ResNet32.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rotation_range=30,  # randomly rotate images in the range (degrees, 0 to 180)
        width_shift_range=0.1,  # randomly shift images horizontally (fraction of total width)
        height_shift_range=0.1,  # randomly shift images vertically (fraction of total height)
        horizontal_flip=True)  # randomly flip images
# Train model
results = ResNet32.fit_generator(datagen.flow(X_train, y_train,
                                 batch_size = 250),
                                 epochs = 100,
                                 steps_per_epoch=200,  # data_size/batch size
                                 validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

Error trace

```
<ipython-input-45-91e0f2fc304c> in <module>()
     71 input_shape=X_train.shape[1:]
     72 optimizer = optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0)
---> 73 ResNet32 = create_model(input_shape=input_shape, classes=2, name='ResNet32')
     74 ResNet32.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
     75 

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/input_spec.py in assert_input_compatibility(input_spec, inputs, layer_name)
    198                      str(len(input_spec)) + ' input(s), '
    199                      'but it received ' + str(len(inputs)) +
--> 200                      ' input tensors. Inputs received: ' + str(inputs))
    201   for input_index, (x, spec) in enumerate(zip(inputs, input_spec)):
    202     if spec is None:

ValueError: Layer conv2d_3 expects 1 input(s), but it received 3 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=32>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=32>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=3>]
```

Answer (score 1):

I have addressed the issue by defining the input to the model as below:

```
def create_model(input_shape, classes, name):
    # Define the input
    X_input = Input(input_shape)
```